# Is it legal to use digital copy if physical copy is broken/lost

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, belgium

I make digital copies of CD/DVD/Vinyls I buy and use those copies myself (on my phone/tablet/laptop).
I am free to use those copies because I purchased the physical version.

If I lose or break the physical version am I still allowed to use the digital versions?

Comment: @NateEldredge, thanks I added the Belgium-tag

Comment: You might want to break this down into 2 separate questions because it might get answered better.

"Is it illegal to make copies of physical purchased CD/DVD/Vinyls?"
and then after you get that answer ask this

"Is it illegal to listen to backups of music after selling the original?"

Comment: @LateralTerminal I know it is legal to make them and use them as long as I have the physical one too. I just need to know what happens when I'm no longer the owner of a (working) physical version

Comment: I think you should ask either "If I lose or break the physical version am I still allowed to use the digital versions?" or "what if I sell them second-hand?" Just so your question is more focused. I find it's better if you ask 2 different questions because you will get a more concise answer. Just a suggestion though

Comment: @LateralTerminal I removed the selling part of the question

Answer (score 1):

*Links in French, sorry, I don't know Dutch/Flemish.*

Yes, the law allowing you to make the copies in the first place doesn't require maintaining the source.

[Article XI.190](http://www.ejustice.just.fgov.be/cgi_loi/loi_a1.pl?language=fr&la=F&cn=2013022819&table_name=loi&&caller=list&fromtab=loi&tri=dd+AS+RANK#Art.XI.190) of the *Code de droit économique*:

> Lorsque l'oeuvre a été licitement divulguée, l'auteur ne peut interdire : [...] 9° la reproduction d'oeuvres, à l'exception des partitions musicales, effectuée dans le cercle de famille et réservée à celui-ci;

Roughly translated,

> Once the work has been legally distributed, the author may not forbid: [...] 9. The reproduction of works, with the exception of sheet music, made within and reserved for the family circle.

For more on private copy in Belgium, see [this government resource](https://economie.fgov.be/fr/themes/propriete-intellectuelle/droit-dauteur/utilisation-dune-oeuvre/copie-privee-et-reprographie).